# Django admin can't access to specific items

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm working in Django with a model (Check) with foreign key.

```
client_id           = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Everything works fine with a regular admin register, but when I use `class ChecksAdminSite`, it crashes. Here is the Client model:

```
class Client (models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' '+ self.surname
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    surname         = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    phone           = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    mail            = models.EmailField(null=True)
    sport           = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender_options=(
        ("F", "femenino"),
        ("M", "masculino"),
        )
    gender          = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, choices=gender_options)
    birth           = models.DateField(null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("clientes:cliente", kwargs={"client_id": self.id})
    pass
```

So, when I get into the admin specific item, it displays the following error:

Field 'id' expected a number but got <Client: Juan Orjuela>.
(Juan Orjuela is the name and the surname of that specific item).

I just can't seem to find a solution or error. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

**Edit**

Stack trace added:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 192, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 172, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 988, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 671, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 796, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 858, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\helpers.py", line 196, in contents
    f, attr, value = lookup_field(field, obj, model_admin)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 276, in lookup_field
    attr = getattr(obj, name)
  File "F:\dev\fitness\fitness\checks\models.py", line 48, in client_check_age
    client = Client.objects.get(pk=self.client_id)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 418, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1319, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 76, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\orjue\.virtualenvs\fitness-w55kuZbn\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1776, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <Client: Juan Orjuela>.
```

Edit:
Foreign key call and client_check_age definition.

```
client_id           = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

@property    
    def client_check_age(self):
        client = Client.objects.get(pk=self.client_id)
        client_check_age = round(((date.today() - client.birth)/timedelta(365)), 2)
        return client_check_age
```

Comment: Could you paste the entire stack trace and the code for the admin form and/or admin.py?

Comment: @DanielButler sorry, I'm a newbie en programing and python. The stack trace is the one displayed on the web browser or on the terminal?

Comment: Hey no worries. It’s the one in the terminal.

Comment: @DanielButler It's quite long: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nJh_yaLxkXd5PkLuGRMrCz1FtwPm59ewp7YNiQjra1I

Comment: It’s best to edit the question and add the stack trace to it

Comment: The problem looks to be in `client_check_age` I think you are passing the client object instead of the client’s Id field. You’d have to include that part of the code and where you are assigning/declaring the client_id field

Comment: @DanielButler Added. I always get so confused on how to call data from a model without calling a model object.

Comment: If my answer was helpful could you up vote it and accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb when using a ForeignKey in django that means the object will be in the attribute. If you are coming at this from a sql background the `foreignkey field` creates a `client_id` column in the database behind the scenes. You never have to worry about that though

```py
client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

@property    
    def client_check_age(self):
        client = Client.objects.get(pk=self.client.id)
        client_check_age = round(((date.today() - client.birth)/timedelta(365)), 2)
        return client_check_age
```

Once you update this code you’ll want to recreate the migrations then migrate the database.